# Strict components in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am preparing for the ColdFusion 9 exam (9A0-127) and find one question that I can't find answer to. In the exam guide point 10 is a question:

***10. Tuning application performance** 
• List and describe the features, benefits, and restrictions when using **strict components***.

Does anyone know what a strict component is?

Comment: No, no idea. Having been using ColdFusion for over a decade, and object oriented CF for about as long. I can firmly say this is not a concept that ColdFusion has. It might be a misrepresentation of some other concept though, but no idea what.

Comment: Maybe it's a badly written reference to the "Disable CFC Type Check" admin setting?

Comment: @PeterBoughton could be, I guess.

Comment: If there is reference material associated with that exam guide, maybe it's defined there.

Comment: Another question: why are you going for CF9 certification, not CF10? CF9's heading towards EOL

Comment: Reference doc for anyone interested:
http://www.adobe.com/support/certification/exams/pdfs/ACE_Exam_Guide_ColdFusion9.pdf

Comment: @AdamCameron There is no CF10 certification - at least not one from Adobe.

Comment: @ScottStroz !!!!! *WHAT*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the context of the question, I'm going to say it was intended to be "script components"

- "Script components" **actually are a thing** in CFML
- They do have some benefits and some restrictions (missing functionality)

It's also possible that it was intended to be strict type checking, as Peter alluded to in his comment:

[image: cfc type checking option in CF Administrator]

---

For your sake, I'd say just be familiar with both features. Good luck on the test.

Comment: I would also recommend anyone who is learning ColdFusion to look at this site http://learncfinaweek.com/. I find it very useful.